# Slide out UIViewController on IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, viewcontroller

How do you make a viewcontroller that slides out and takes up part of the screen such as ones which may be seen on popular apps like Facebook, Rdio and Tinder? So you do a side swipe and a viewController will slide out and take up approximately three quarters of the screen and may have a tableView within it? Also, would this design be made using storyboard or interface builder?

Comment: take a look this Github example:-https://github.com/ipup/PPRevealSideViewController and impliment it into your poject

Comment: This is a variant of what is used in Tinder. An earlier commit was the actual version used in Tinder though it has had some changes since. It's not truly maintained. SignNow uses the more modern commit. https://github.com/badeen/JLBSlidingPanelsViewController

Answer (score 2):

What i used in my project was MMDrawerController (Mutual Mobile Drawer Controller)

https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMDrawerController

it provides full control and variety of effects, transitions, guestures. also you can slide the panel from either left or right side.

Answer (score 2):

There are a very large amount of frameworks that do this.  The two most popular ones are [JASidePanels](https://github.com/gotosleep/JASidePanels) (which I personally use) and [ECSSlidingViewController](https://github.com/edgecase/ECSlidingViewController).  You could also implement it yourself, but this will be more complicated.  A place to start is to have a "bottom view controller" that loads and manages the other view controllers, or at least manages their views.  If you have the patience, this route is obviously preferable as you can then really control the behavior of your app.  That being said, these are great starts.

In these examples they use a combination of both programmatic management of view controllers, and the story board.  It really depends on how you want to manage it personally.  I personally like to "paint" my view controller basics in the story board and instantiate them using their storyboard IDs in order to give myself a good idea of what is going on visually.

Answer (score 0):

You should Tate a look at [ViewDeck](https://github.com/Inferis/ViewDeck). Just download it and take a look at it it's higly customazible and it's Identical to the facebook app